# How do I add small words to an entry in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

Like this.
[image]

I mean how to add the red words in the figure.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section 1}
% This is an example.
\section{section 2}
% This is an example.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That depends on your setup. For example the `memoir` class has features to do this. You can of course steal the code from `memoir` if you're using a different class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you show me more details?